# What's the purpose of the capacitor in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, multivibrator

[image: cap]

If this trigger pulse is starting the process of sweep generation, seems to me like it would be going directly to the base of the transistor (Q701) to switch it on and off, so the series of multiple transistors downstream can do their thing to generate a nice big sawtooth wave. However, with a capacitor being placed in-between the input signal and the transistor, it seems to me like it's killing the signal. The signal isn't actually doing anything now. The signal is dying post-capacitor. How is that productive?

[image: cap2]

Comment: What do you mean it's killing the signal? It's an DC block capacitor which allows the input pulses to become superimposed on whatever DC bias is being applied to the BJT base. That BJT isn't just acting as a simple switch. It's being DC-biased (or overridden) by that stabilizing circuit at the bottom so it behaves in a particular way.

Comment: Is no signal post-capacitor an expected finding? My sweep circuit is not working, and I have no signal post-cap.

Comment: It is not unusual for old capacitors to dry up and act like an open circuit. Try replacing with exact value and voltage. Note that EE.SE does not get involved with repairs of consumer products.

Comment: A vintage analog oscilloscope from 1969 doesn't seem like a typical consumer product. It has schematics!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments C701 is a DC blocking capacitor. The 5.6 volt bias voltage is part of a DC servo-loop to keep the final output saw-tooth at a specific DC level. C701 combined with a low resistance input does modify the square wave input, but as shown it is the edge that this circuit syncs to.

Without the DC blocking capacitor, which does have a high-pass filter effect as well, this circuit loses filtering of the square wave and loses the DC isolation it needs. C701 allows the square wave input to have most any DC reference, including zero volts, without upsetting the performance of the sweep generator.

Before being put into use this circuit had to pass military testing for accuracy and long-term stability, and a servo-loop is a good way to do that. Part of the "Hold-off" circuit feeds back part of the saw-tooth to the same 5.6 volt node. This prevents re-triggering of the sweep generator in the middle of a sweep.

The upper section of the sweep generator inserts a blanking pulse so the retrace of the sweep is blanked out, similar to analog TV.

Comment: Can you tell me what I should expect to read post-capacitor? If no signal, then how does this circuit create a sawtooth without something triggering it?

Comment: Note that there are manual controls to set a default sweep rate if no signal.